# Return state of a row when executing a function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, trigger, plpgsql

For years I have been creating functions that are executed by triggers, and in the function I always returned `OLD` (for `DELETE` triggers) or `NEW` (for `INSERT` or `UPDATE` triggers).

Is it mandatory to specify `RETURNS trigger` and put `return NEW/OLD` at the end of the function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fun_clear_trask_draft()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$

BEGIN
    
    DELETE FROM drafts WHERE task_id = NEW.task_id;

    RETURN NEW;

END;
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_clear_task_draft
AFTER UPDATE ON task
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.has_drafts = 'Y')
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE fun_clear_trask_draft();
```

Some tables have more than one associated trigger for insert and update.

Answer (score 3):

You were doing the right thing. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html):

> The trigger function must be declared as a function taking no arguments and returning type trigger.

So yes, you have to declare the function as `RETURNS trigger`.

> Trigger functions invoked by per-row triggers can return a table row [...] to the calling executor, if they choose. A row-level trigger fired before an operation has the following choices:
>
> - It can return `NULL` to skip the operation for the current row. This instructs the executor to not perform the row-level operation that invoked the trigger (the insertion, modification, or deletion of a particular table row).
> - For row-level `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers only, the returned row becomes the row that will be inserted or will replace the row being updated. This allows the trigger function to modify the row being inserted or updated.
>
> A row-level `BEFORE` trigger that does not intend to cause either of these behaviors must be careful to return as its result the same row that was passed in (that is, the `NEW` row for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers, the `OLD` row for `DELETE` triggers).

So yes, if you don't want to modify the new row, you have to `RETURN NEW` for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers, and you should `RETURN OLD` for `DELETE` triggers if you don't want to cancel the `DELETE`.

If you have several triggers on a table, the returned value of each trigger becomes the input for the next trigger:

> If more than one trigger is defined for the same event on the same relation, the triggers will be fired in alphabetical order by trigger name. In the case of `BEFORE` and `INSTEAD OF` triggers, the possibly-modified row returned by each trigger becomes the input to the next trigger. If any `BEFORE` or `INSTEAD OF` trigger returns `NULL`, the operation is abandoned for that row and subsequent triggers are not fired (for that row).

See [my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/what-to-return-from-a-postgresql-row-level-trigger/) on the topic for some detail. I have come to `RETURN coalesce(NEW, OLD)` in trigger functions that are fired on `INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE`.